# XML schema validation: Multiple erro like cvc-complex-type.2.4.a & cvc-complex-type.2.3

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I'm trying to validate my XML document against my XML schema.

This is my schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--Created with Liquid XML Studio 2012 Developer Edition (Trial) 10.1.8.4306 (http://www.liquid-technologies.com)-->
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="MSG">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="EnTete" type="EnTeteType" />
                <xs:element name="OME" type="OMEType" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="Type" type="xs:string" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="Version" type="xs:decimal" use="required" />
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="EnTeteType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="Source" />
            <xs:element ref="Creation" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="Source">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:enumeration value="NEBEFI" />
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Creation">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:maxLength value="12" />
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="OMEType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="Derniere-Modif" />
            <xs:element ref="Date-Mesure" />
            <xs:element name="Reference" type="ReferenceType" />
            <xs:element name="Puissance" type="PuissType" />
            <xs:element ref="Total" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="Nom" type="xs:string" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="Derniere-Modif" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:element name="Date-Mesure">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:maxLength value="14" />
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="ReferenceType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="Nature" />
            <xs:element ref="Statut" />
            <xs:element ref="Type-Gest" />
            <xs:element ref="Gest" />
            <xs:element ref="Type-Res" />
            <xs:element ref="Nb-h" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="Nature" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:element name="Statut">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
                <xs:enumeration value="0" />
                <xs:enumeration value="1" />
                <xs:enumeration value="2" />
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Type-Gest" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:element name="Type-Res" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:element name="Gest">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:length value="10" />
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Nb-h">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
                <xs:enumeration value="23" />
                <xs:enumeration value="24" />
                <xs:enumeration value="25" />
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Puiss">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="Val" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="Unite" type="xs:string" use="required" />
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Val" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:element name="Total">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
                <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                    <xs:attribute name="Unite" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="PuissType">
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element ref="Puiss" />
        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

and this is my XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<MSG xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance" Type="Publication" Version="1.0">
 <EnTete>
  <Source>NEBEFI</Source> 
  <Creation>201208092324</Creation> 
</EnTete>
 <OME Nom="Effacements RE">
  <Derniere-Modif>20120809232419</Derniere-Modif> 
  <Date-Mesure>20120809000000</Date-Mesure> 
 <Reference>
  <Nature>ACHAT</Nature> 
  <Statut>2</Statut> 
  <Type-Gest>RE</Type-Gest> 
  <Gest>RE_ENEL_RE</Gest> 
  <Type-Res>D</Type-Res> 
  <Nb-h>24</Nb-h> 
</Reference>
 <Puiss Unite="MW">
                <Val>1.500</Val>
                <Val>1.500</Val>
                <Val>1.500</Val>
                <Val>1.500</Val>
                <Val>1.500</Val>
                <Val>1.500</Val>
                <Val>1.500</Val>
                <Val>1.500</Val>
                <Val>1.500</Val>
                <Val>1.500</Val>
                <Val>1.500</Val>
                <Val>1.500</Val>
                <Val>1.500</Val>
                <Val>1.500</Val>
                <Val>1.500</Val>
                <Val>1.500</Val>
                <Val>1.500</Val>
                <Val>1.500</Val>
                <Val>1.500</Val>
                <Val>1.500</Val>
                <Val>1.500</Val>
                <Val>1.500</Val>
                <Val>1.500</Val>
                <Val>1.500</Val>
                <Val>1.500</Val>
                <Val>1.500</Val>
                <Val>1.500</Val>
                <Val>1.500</Val>
                <Val>1.500</Val>
                <Val>1.500</Val>
                <Val>1.500</Val>
                <Val>1.500</Val>
                <Val>1.500</Val>
                <Val>1.500</Val>
                <Val>1.500</Val>
                <Val>1.500</Val>
                <Val>1.500</Val>
                <Val>1.500</Val>
                <Val>1.500</Val>
                <Val>1.500</Val>
                <Val>1.500</Val>
                <Val>1.500</Val>
                <Val>1.500</Val>
                <Val>1.500</Val>
                <Val>1.500</Val>
                <Val>1.500</Val>
                <Val>1.500</Val>
                <Val>1.500</Val> 
  </Puiss>
  <Total Unite="MWh">5961</Total> 
  </OME>
</MSG>
```

Now when I'm validating the document (via Eclipse) I get following message:

> Not valid. Error - Line 18, 21: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;
>   lineNumber: 18; columnNumber: 21; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid
>   content was found starting with element 'Puiss'. One of '{Puissance}'
>   is expected.
>
> Error - Line 69, 9: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 69;
>   columnNumber: 9; cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'OME' cannot have
>   character [children], because the type's content type is element-only.
>
> Error - Line 70, 7: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 70;
>   columnNumber: 7; cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'MSG' cannot have
>   character [children], because the type's content type is element-only.

This messages doesn't make any sense, and it's very hard (impossible?) to search the web for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error at least is very clear - according to your schema the next-to-last child element of OME should be named `Puissance`, but the parser has found `Puiss` instead. In particular, reading the rest of your schema it looks like it's expecting

```
<Puissance>
  <Puiss Unite="MW">
    <!-- Val elements as before -->
  </Puiss>
</Puissance>
```

If this is your own schema you may want to replace the

```
<xs:element name="Puissance" type="PuissType" />
```

in your `OMEType` with a simple

```
<xs:element ref="Puiss" />
```

For the other two errors I agree, they don't seem to make much sense unless there's some invisible non-printing characters in the XML, but I've known Eclipse get quite confused by certain classes of error in the past and start reporting problems that aren't there - once you fix the first error you may find the others disappear too.